# Increment CSS Class or ID Value from Dynamically Added Table Row/Form

Tags: javascript

I have a form which is dynamically added, its working ok.
But my problem is that the ID or CLASS is also duplicated causing the SELECT CHAINED to Fail.
Im Planning to implement an incrementing ID or CLASS so that when i Add Row, it will just add a number to the ID or CLASS making it Unique.
Or if you have other suggestions, please help me with this.

Kindly Check it Here.

http://jsfiddle.net/yL4VE/5/

Thank You in Advance.

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="100" name="country">
                <option value="USA">USA</option>
                <option value="CANADA">CANADA</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="200" name="city">
                <option value="CHICAGO">CHICAGO</option>
                <option value="HOUSTON">HOUSTON</option>
                <option value="ONTARIO">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button id="btnAdicionar">Add New</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".city_list").chained(".country_list");
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        //add table row
        function Adicionar() {
            $("#mytable tbody").append(
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>" +
                "<select name='country' class='incremented value'>" +
                "<option value='USA'>USA</option>" +
                "<option value='CANADA'>CANADA</option>" +
                "</select></td>" +
                "<td>" +
                "<select name='city' class='incremented value'>" +
                "<option value='CHICAGO'>CHICAGO</option>" +
                "<option value='HOUSTON'HOUSTON/option>" +
                "<option value='ONTARIO'ONTARIO/option>" +
                "</select></td>" +
                "</tr>");

            $(".btnSalvar").bind("click", Salvar);
            $(".btnExcluir").bind("click", Excluir);

            //chained select for dynamically added row
            $(".incremented value").chained(".incremented value");
        };

        //Some Code for EDIT and DELETE Table Row Goes here.

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a form. There is also a closing tbody tag but no opening tag (btw, they're optional).

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to have two different classes: `.incremented` and `.value`

then your selector needs to be `.incremented.value`

```
$(".incremented.value")
```

Otherwise make it one class:

```
class="incremented_value"
```

and selector:

```
$(".incremented_value")
```